# For Random Access Iterator (vector iterator), are the iterators C++ style pointers?

Tags: c++, iterator, random-access

I have the following code to randomize the elements in a list container:

```
    #include <vector>
    #include <list>
    #include <iterator>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

        template<class RandomAccesIterator>
        void randomize(RandomAccesIterator iterBegin, RandomAccesIterator iterEnd)
        {
            while (iterBegin != iterEnd)
            {
                iter_swap(iterBegin, iterBegin + rand() % (iterEnd - iterBegin));
                ++iterBegin;
            }
        }
```

And then later in main():

```
int main()
{
    //container used as to apply algorithm to.
    list<int> List = {34,77,16,2,35,76,18,2};

    //randomize example.
    cout << "calling randomize on sorted vector: " << endl;
    List.sort();
    vector<int> temp(List.begin(), List.end());
    cout << "before randomize: " << endl;
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = temp.begin(); it != temp.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    randomize(temp.begin(),temp.end());
    cout << "after randomize: " << endl;
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = temp.begin(); it != temp.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
    cout << endl<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I had a couple of questions:

1. I believe performing iterEnd - iterBegin (as shown in the template function) is a valid operation, because both iterEnd and iterBegin are C++ style pointers. and subtracting these pointers gives the distance between them. Am I correct?
2. I tried the following in the immediate window:

```
iterEnd
{-33686019}
    [ptr]: 0x00ba4f78 {-33686019}
    [Raw View]: {...}
```

it means iterEnd is a pointer, whose value is 0x00ba4f78, and it points to the garbage value of -33686019. I believe I am correct here?

So, the iterator is a pointer, for random access iterators. Is it true for all iterator types (Input/output iterators, Forward iterators, BiDirectional iterators)? If those iterators are not C++ style pointers, then what are those?

3. I also tried the following in the immediate window:

```
&iterEnd
0x006ff368 {-33686019}
    [ptr]: 0x00ba4f78 {-33686019}
    [Raw View]: 0x006ff368 {...}
&&iterEnd
expected an expression
```

Why is &iterEnd giving me an address? It should give me the message "expected an expression", as, &&iterEnd does.

4. How are random access iterators implemented? - I am asking because iterEnd gives me a pointer value and, &iterEnd also gives me a (different) pointer value. Is the random access iterator a pointer within a pointer?

Comment: *I believe performing iterEnd - iterBegin (as shown in the template function) is a valid operation, because both iterEnd and iterBegin are C++ style pointers* -- No.  Iterators are not pointers, but all pointers are iterators.   The internals of a vector iterator is implementation-defined.  One such famous case is Visual C++, where 6.0, vector iterators were simple pointers, but subsequent versions of that compiler changed them to a `struct`.

Comment: Even though the exact iterator type is unspecified and might or might not be a raw pointer, the subtraction is guaranteed to be valid, since this is a requirement of all [Random Access Iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For Random Access Iterator (vector iterator), are the iterators C++
>   style pointers?

Short answer -- it depends on the compiler.

The internals of a `vector` iterator is implementation-defined.  The `std::vector<T>::iterator` could have `operator -` overloaded, thus it gives the illusion of pointer subtraction.  Thus if you assume that `vector` iterators are simple pointers, writing code assuming they are simple pointers will break using various compilers, while for other compilers it will compile successfully.

One such famous case is Visual C++, where in version 6.0, `vector` iterators were simple pointers, thus many authors at that time using that compiler would write code with the assumption that a `std::vector<T>::iterator` was just a `T*`.  The code compiled successfully and worked correctly due to the fact that vector iterators *were* implemented as pointers.

An example would be something like this:

```
#include <vector>

void foo(char *c)
{
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<char> vc;
   foo(vc.begin());
}
```

No compile errors, since `vc.begin()` was a simple `char *`.

Then came the subsequent versions of Visual C++, and that code that used to compile successfully under 6.0 is now broken.  The `std::vector<T>::iterator` was no longer a simple `T*`, but a `struct`.  A lot of code based on the (faulty) reasoning of an iterator being a simple pointer had to be changed for Visual C++ > version 6.0.